# Getting the PHP IF statement right

Tags: php, mysql

What I want to do is create a query that would say if the return radio is selected, then search the db. If not, then continue with the original query.

This is what I have so far and (not suprisingly) it doesn't work

```
if ($ret == 'y')
        $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  search_v Currency='$currency' AND rout_to='$sfrom' AND rout_from='$sto' AND date_avialable='$stoda'") or die(mysql_error()) ;
}
```

I also use the same IF statement to include a file, but its not willing to send anything either:

```
if ($ret == 'y')
        include ("return.php");
}
```

Comment: theres an input field with the value 'ret' so i parse it through using the get variable

Comment: Either add an opening curly bracket after "if($ret =='y')" or remove the bottom one. Try running it after that and let us know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you're missing an opening curly brace. Simply adding one like so should fix that:

```
if ($ret == 'y')
{
    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  search_v Currency='$currency' AND rout_to='$sfrom' AND rout_from='$sto' AND date_avialable='$stoda'") or die(mysql_error()) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what was wrong with it. Cant believe I forgot something so small...

Answer (score 1):

If statements should be of the form:

```
if ($boolean_expression) {

}
```

Note the open bracket; `{`. What you have here will still evaluate, because if statements without brackets will assume the next line, and only the next line, are part of the if clause. However, following that up with a close bracket will muck with any other scope you have; anything after that point is unlikely to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Missing `{` opening curly brace here ...

```
if ($ret == 'y')  
{                   **---------------------> MISSING**
include ("return.php"); 
}
```